# Colored output from fabric script

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

I'm trying to color my output from fabric script, so I do something like this:

```
local("hg pull")
print(blue(local("hg update")))
local("hg status")
```

I expected to have the 'hg update' response print in blue, but instead I get the result of the next line 'hg status' in blue.

In the Fabric documentation there are examples with coloring hard-coded strings, which work as I expect. Do you have any advice on how I can color response to just a single local command?

Comment: Just for a complete picture for newbies: ``from fabric.colors import blue, green, red`` (etc.) imports colors in Fabric. See [the docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/colors.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
local("hg pull")
res = local("hg update", capture=True)
print(blue(res))
local("hg status")
```

[Edit] you also need the `capture=True` to fetch the output.

Comment: Now it works (with capture=True). I try to write this in one line as print(blue(local("hg update", capture=True))) and it still prints output in blue color. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Color functions in fabric are for simple strings, not for command output. But you can implement your own context manager for coloring:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
BLUE = 34  # https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/1.7/fabric/colors.py#L40

@contextmanager
def colored_output(color):
    print("\033[%sm" % color, end="")
    yield
    print("\033[0m", end="")

with colored_output(BLUE):
    local("hg update")
```

Another way to achive your goal is to use `local(..., capture=True)`, but you will not see any output until command is finished ([help on local command](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.local)).

Comment: This gives `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` pointing to `end=""`